# Best syntax to test event target in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a keypress handler bound to all input elements on a form, and I need to perform different operations depending on which element received the keypress. All 3 variations below work, but I'd like to know if one (or something else) is preferred and why.

```
$(':input').keypress(function(e) {
  if($(this).attr('id') === 'foo')  // option 1
    console.log('foo'); 
  if($(this)[0] === $('#bar')[0])   // option 2
    console.log('bar');
  if(e.target === $('#baz')[0])     // option 3
    console.log('baz'); 
});
```

There are few elements on the page, so performance isn't really a concern. It's more of a stylistic/standards/readability issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option #4:

```
$(':input').keypress(function(e) {
  if(this.id == 'foo') console.log('foo'); 
});
```

`this` will be a DOM element in the handler, no need for the jQuery object checks, just do a string comparison against the native [`.id` DOM property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.id), it's clear, concise and the fastest - win, win here.

Comment: Yes, of course you're right, it's a wonder I missed the simplest solution. I think I get stuck in jQuery mode and can't see the forest for the trees. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The nicest way is none of these.  Use `this.id` rather than `$(this).attr('id')` for performance:

```
if (this.id == 'foo') {
```

Even nicer would be to use the ID in the selector, if what you are actually looking for is the input element with the ID `foo`.

```
$('#foo').keypress(function(e) {
```

This will be substantially quicker than `:input`.

Comment: You're changing the binding context of the selector, his selector binds to `n` elements, you're binds to one, this may result in a *lot* more code.

Comment: @Nick Edited for clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but to Nick's comment, I don't want that much specificity in the selector.